# How to get number of times per month a user logs in to the Confluence site

Tags: confluence

I would like to report some information about a user in my confluence site. But i have a problem that is "How to get number of times per month a user logs in to my site". 
Had anyone do this before?

my user's information report form look just like this:

user name - login times - 2011/08

Answer (score 2):

You could write an EventListener component that listens for a special ConfluenceEvent, the [LoginEvent](http://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-confluence/latest/com/atlassian/confluence/event/events/security/LoginEvent.html) and is triggered when a user successfully logs into Confluence.

When the event is triggered, just save this information in a map and persist it using BandanaPersistence or the ActiveObject API as described in the [Confluence Developer Documentation](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFDEV/Confluence+Developer+Documentation).

Now that the information for your stats are persisted you could write a Macro to ouput the information on a Confluence page.